# Xamarin.Forms ScrollView reduces its height on ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using ListView inside ScrollView

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Neither" Padding="0" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView  x:Name="List"  ItemsSource="{Binding VisCon}"  HorizontalOptions="Fill" HasUnevenRows="True"
                        Margin="0"
                        ItemTapped="List_TappedAndroid"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        ios:ListView.GroupHeaderStyle="Grouped"
                        Scrolled="List_OnScrolled"
                        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"                           
                        RefreshCommand="{Binding RefCom}" 
                        SeparatorVisibility="None" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefresh}" 
                        CachingStrategy="Recycle">
```

On Android it works excellent.

But on iOS there is randomly appearing bug. ScrollView reduces it's height from below, so it seems to be cut. The content inside it is OK and it scrolls well, but empty space appears on the bottom of the screen.

Bug fixes if i pop the page and push it again.

Comment: Sounds like something isn't automatically filling the screen height. Is `ScrollView` inside a `ContentPage`?  What does the XAML look like, from the top of XAML source file, to the line `<ScrollView ...>`?  If you set different background colors on the page, the scrollview, and the listview, which of those colors fills the area at bottom of page?

Comment: Do not nest scrolls, LisView already has it own scroll

Comment: @Muraki In addition to ListView, there are other control in Contentpage Scorllview, if there is just ListView, you don't need to add Scrollview fro ListView. If you must add Scrollview, please provide screenshot about your problem.

Comment: ScrollView was used to avoid the bug using "FillAndCollapse", but it didn't work. It started to appear rarely but still appears.

Comment: @Muraki I create simple sample by adding ListView in Scrollview, having no problems for Android and ios, if you still have problems, you can create simple sample that can reproduce your problem at gtihub or onedrive, I will download your sample to test.